# Mate Dictionary

Tags: fonts, dictionary

Please help me to increase the font size in Mate Dictionary program my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS is burdened with. The "preferences" look like it's easy whereas it's not.
Thank you. Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible.

You can increase the font for printout -

- *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Print*, *Print Font* - set font and font size here

but not for screen.

So I have reported feature request to MATE Developers - https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-utils/issues/222 .

---

There is a workaround - you can change *Document Font* in *Appearance Properties* (`mate-appearance-properties`) → *Fonts*:

compare 12 pt

[image]

with 18 pt:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, NOrbert. Good luck! :)

Comment: It is possible by workaround, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Sounds good. Actually I tried that but, probably, not as far as MD might be improved. Will do. Take care. Igor

Comment: This is to confirm the above answer. Menu – Preferences – MATE Tweak – Windows – Fonts – Fonts – Appearance Preferences – Fonts – Document font. And chose the font & size good for you. Thanks again. Igor

Answer (score 0):

I recognized my one-year-ago question. Now, for me it works this way: Main Menu – Preferences – MATE Tweak – Windows – Fonts – Fonts – Appearance Preferences – Fonts – Document font – Liberation Sans Regular 28.